# JavaScript While Loop Not Looping Fully

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to do a while loop with the conditions that the number is lower than 5, and it's divisible by 3 and 5.

Here's my code:

```
    var beginningNumber = 5;

    while (beginningNumber <= 50 && beginningNumber % 5 === 0 && beginningNumber % 3 === 0) {
      console.log(beginningNumber);
      beginningNumber++;
}
```

My console log isn't typing out anything.  I've checked if I can use multiple operators in a while loop I can.  I'm not sure what's happening.  What's the issue?

Comment: Your condition makes it halt as soon as the `beginningNumber` is not a multiple of `15`. You should take that out of the condition of the loop, and put it inside the loop as a `if` condition.

Comment: `5 % 3 !== 0` so it never enters the `while`.

Comment: Oh my God... that's so obvious.  It's trying to achieve the conditions.

Comment: I don't know what I was thinking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`beginningNumber % 3 === 0` is not true for `5`.

```js
var beginningNumber = 15;
while (beginningNumber <= 50 && beginningNumber % 5 === 0 && beginningNumber % 3 === 0) {
  console.log(beginningNumber);
  beginningNumber++;
}
```

Set it to something like 15 and it'll work... once, because then it'll become 16.

What you probably are looking for is something like this:

```js
var beginningNumber = 5;
while (beginningNumber <= 50) {
  if (beginningNumber % 5 === 0 && beginningNumber % 3 === 0) {
    console.log(beginningNumber);
  }
  
  beginningNumber++;
}
```

This will let you loop through all the numbers from `5` to `50`, and output each number that meets the conditions.

Answer (score 1):

Your condition is never being fulfilled five is not divisible by 3 so the loop is never run. Have you considered using a for loop for this and doing an if statement in a condition

```js
for (var beginningNumber = 5; beginningNumber <= 50; beginningNumber++) {
  if (beginningNumber % 5 === 0 && beginningNumber % 3 === 0) {
    console.log(beginningNumber);
  }
}
```